# RaphaelJS applying a custom transform

Tags: svg, raphael, transform, scale

I am having trouble with applying a transformation to each path in my SVG. I know the exact transform I need to add as I am using a map from wikimedia and have tested it by adding it using firebug/chromebug.

I need to add:

```
transform="translate(0,239) scale(0.016963,-0.016963)"
```

This is an example of what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/m7t4X/1/

If you inspect it, each path looks like this:

```
<path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ccc6ae" d="M16760,5958C16752,5945,16745,5920,16743,5901C16740,5859,16734,5853,16710,5868C16694,5878,16690,5878,16690,5866C16690,5858,16696,5849,16703,5846C16709,5843,16705,5843,16693,5846C16670,5851,16666,5845,16669,5808C16670,5799,16666,5789,16660,5785C16655,5782,16650,5770,16650,5760C16650,5747,16645,5743,16635,5746C16626,5750,16620,5746,16620,5737C16620,5717,16549,5667,16495,5649C16473,5642,16451,5632,16446,5628C16440,5624,16426,5620,16413,5620C16395,5620,16390,5615,16390,5593C16390,5577,16381,5552,16371,5536C16351,5506,16351,5482,16371,5367C16383,5300,16383,5298,16354,5242C16338,5211,16321,5182,16317,5179C16282,5154,16269,5063,16294,5016C16302,5000,16306,4972,16303,4946C16300,4920,16302,4900,16309,4896C16315,4892,16320,4881,16320,4871C16320,4849,16350,4820,16373,4820C16382,4820,16390,4816,16390,4810C16390,4795,16442,4799,16464,4815C16475,4823,16496,4830,16511,4830C16541,4830,16580,4870,16580,4899C16580,4908,16586,4924,16594,4935C16601,4946,16613,4980,16620,5010C16628,5040,16642,5081,16651,5101C16661,5121,16675,5159,16681,5186C16688,5213,16710,5278,16731,5332C16752,5385,16772,5446,16775,5467C16787,5539,16790,5550,16803,5547C16815,5545,16816,5554,16804,5630L16797,5675L16817,5651L16837,5626L16854,5658C16866,5682,16868,5695,16860,5709C16855,5720,16850,5749,16850,5773C16850,5797,16845,5832,16839,5851C16825,5895,16786,5979,16780,5980C16777,5980,16768,5970,16760,5958Z" stroke-opacity="1" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1;"></path>
```

If I add it manually via firebug etc to change the start to look like this:

```
<path  transform="translate(0,239) scale(0.016963,-0.016963)" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ccc6ae" d="
```

then it works perfectly. I just cannot replicate this.

I have tried various ways of adding the transform, but none have worked fully. 
From what I gather, RaphaelJS is backwards compatible so all of the solutions I have found (which haven't fully worked anyway) wouldn't have worked in any older IEs for instance.

The first thing I tried was to change:

```
paper.setViewBox(0, 0, w, h, true);
```

to:

```
paper.setViewBox(true);
```

However this did not work with the shapes I am using (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Continents.svg)

This is where I got the transform amounts from (can be seen if you view source).

Please advise on where I'm going wrong, and how I could go about adding this.

Many thanks!

**---------------------------------EDIT -------------------------------------**

After applying the fix below, I have found it appears to be displaying the SVG rotated 180degrees and flipped horizontally. I don't quite understand why either.

This is how it is meant to look:
[image]

And this is how it comes out:
[image]

(also noticed I'm missing south america despite it being referenced)

This is a new fiddle of how it currently looks:

http://jsfiddle.net/wrayvon/m7t4X/3/

Thanks again

Comment: That is a HUGE view box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform should work, but I think you just need to set a bigger width/height for the viewBox. These should be for the co-ordinate space, not for pixels on screen.

```
var w = 15000;
var h = 25000;

paper.setViewBox(10000, 0, w, h, true);
```

Should do it. You can also transform it if you want, by adding something like the following to the element when created.

```
.transform('t2000,1000')
```

edit: As you have changed the SVG... If there are transforms in the original, you will probably need to apply the same transforms to the elements...so a line like this...

```
var c = paper.path(worldmap.shapes[country]).attr({ stroke: "#ccc6ae", fill: "#ff0000", "stroke-opacity": 1 }).transform('s1,-1,13000,10000');
```

I'm just guessing the centre point to scale from there (13,000,10,000 its probably a bit more), you will need to figure that separately.

Or you could match the scale as per the original SVG, and then you probably won't need to change the viewBox (apart from matching the original).

Original [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7t4X/2/)

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7t4X/4/)

Comment: Alas, I missed that it was displaying upside down and flipped! Please see my latest edit. Thanks

Comment: Thats because its upside down in the original and each group has a transform with a negative Y scale applied.

Comment: Ahh I see. I tried adding 'transform="translate(100, 0) scale(-1, 1)' after I specify the stroke and fill and it doesn't appear to do anything. On inspection, it's just pulling this through: transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)". I wish I understood this more. Any help to put it the correct way would be very much appreciated

Comment: I've edited the answer, which includes a scale, you will need to figure the centre of the map to scale around if you are bothered about precision (the last pair of arguments in the transform).

Comment: That is great, thank you once again. Most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with the exact same problem. Your question is the clearest articulation of it.

As a bit of background, I found an SVG map of the US  and all of its counties. I thought, "great, I'll just copy these paths into Raphael, and Bob's your uncle". So, I did, but it appeared exactly upside down after the import. I considered applying some math to the paths, but decided against it. Instead I investigated the transform() option too.

In the transform method, there are a few options. One of the options is to use the matrix ("m"). The matrix method has 6 options. - see [here](http://cancerbero.mbarreneche.com/raphaeltut/#heading_toc_j_85)
for more details. But the matrix setting for the 'as-the-path' dictates is this:

```
.transform("m1,0,0,1,0,0");
```

If you make the 4th place negative, it will invert your image.

```
.transform("m1,0,0,-1,0,0");
```

HOWEVER...it has to choose a location for the axis on which to flip. That, as far as I can tell, is the top edge of the the container div. So your image is now above you. Use the viewbox to find it and zoom as you desire:

```
R.setViewBox(x,y,x-size,y-size);//The Y (second param) will need to be negative.
```

Here's my example to find my shape: (make your 200's into 1000's to more easily locate you image, then play with the numbers to center, and enlarge)

```
R.setViewBox(0,-575,200,200);
```

The downside using the transform is the overhead of drawing, then relocating the images. In my case, I am less concerned about this as speed doesn't seem to be affected, which may be due to the relatively small number of paths involved.